# Pandas Pivot Table - Hierarchy between Column and Value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table displaying monthly aggregated values of "Lead" and "Sale". For example, below 2019-01, I want to see both Lead value and Sale value.

However, my code below generates the "Lead" and "Sale" separately on top of the dates. What should i do?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Y/M": ["2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09"],
         "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two","one", "one", "two", "two"],
         "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small","small", "large", "small", "small", "large"],
         "Lead": [10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
         "Sale":[4, 10, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 5, 9]})
df

table = pd.pivot_table(df, columns='Y/M', 
                       values=['Lead','Sale'],
                       index=['B','C'],
                       aggfunc=np.sum, margins = False,fill_value=0)
table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
table.reorder_levels([1,0], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```